# Who first explicitly wrote the determinant identity $\det(1+AB) = \det(1+BA)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, math-history, random-matrices

Though this identity can be easily proved, I am wondering **who first explicitly write it in such a simple and elegant form?**

I check several textbooks on linear algebra but find no evidence (see below the list of books I have checked).
The [entry on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weinstein%E2%80%93Aronszajn_identity) calls it the Weinstein–Aronszajn identity now but [previously attributed it to J. J. Sylvester](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Weinstein%E2%80%93Aronszajn_identity&oldid=850880692).
In the [blog of Terence Tao](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2013/01/13/matrix-identities-as-derivatives-of-determinant-identities), he calls it the Weinstein–Aronszajn identity with a link to the Wikipedia page, but tags and comments for that article imply that he used to call it the 'Sylvester determinant identity'.
The wiki page does not give direct references to the explicit form.
The book referred to in the proof calls this identity 'Sylvester's determinant theorem'.
The old version of the wiki page refers to [an 1851 paper by Sylvester](https://doi.org/10.1080/14786445108646735).
I have checked it and did not see the explicit form.

In conclusion, no direct reference is given for the explicit form.
So I am very confused.
For the identity in the title, who should be attributed to?

In case that asking about attribution may offend some mathematicians, I would like to focus on who first use the finite/infinite version of this identity to solve problems, especially in the explicit form.
**A direct reference would be a good answer.**
By 'direct reference' I mean a paper — a paper which (1) contains the explicit form of the identity, (2) applies it to solve problems and (3) is authored by whoever presumably be attributed to.

---

Textbooks I have checked:

1. C.D. Meyer, Matrix Analysis and Applied Linear Algebra (2000)
2. R.A. Horn & C.R. Johnson, Matrix Analysis, 2nd ed. (2012)

Comment: This should be an hsm.se question.

Comment: Nachman Aronszajn definitely could not do it before Sylvester.

Comment: Weinstein and Aronszajn presumably get credit for the infinite-dimensional application, which Sylvester would definitely not have done.

Comment: @J.G. Actually there is [a similar post](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/12756) there, but no satisfactory answer is present.

Comment: Why is the attribution to Weinstein and Aronszajn given in that post unsatisfactory?

Comment: @LeeMosher Because no direct references is given. See my update on the question.

Comment: By "direct reference" do you mean a reference to a paper by Weinstein and/or Aronszajn? And would finding such a reference be a good answer to your post? If so then I suggest editing your post to clarify this issue.

Comment: @LeeMosher Thanks. The post is updated.

Comment: @MishaLavrov Does the community of mathematics credit this identity to Weinstein and Aronszajn? I am out of the community and do not find a reputable linear algebra textbook talking about the credit.

Comment: I do not know. Like the author of the HSM post, I tracked down "Weinstein-Aronszajn" to Kato's 1966 textbook, where I don't see an identity as simple as this one stated. But if the attribution to Weinstein and Aronszajn is correct, then I expect that it's because they extended a finite-dimensional identity to the infinite-dimensional case.

Comment: Actually, identity (6.10) on p.246 of Kato (any edition's fine) says $$(-\zeta)^m \omega_P(\zeta;T) = \omega(\zeta;T,A)$$ which I unpack from previous definitions to mean something very similar to the extended identity $$\det(AB - \lambda I_m) = (-\lambda)^{m-n} \det(BA - \lambda I_n).$$ They are dealing with infinite-dimensional matrices so the statement does need to be more technical than that; just a plain $(-\lambda)^{m-n}$ makes no sense in that setting. The next step would be to go through the bibliography to see which of Weinstein and/or Aronszajn's articles this formula comes from.

Answer (score 4):

This is known as "*Sylvester's determinant theorem*". I don't know who first stated it as an explicit theorem, but the theorem's name originated from the stronger theorem that if $A$ and $B$ are square matrices, then $AB$ and $BA$ have the same eigenvalues and characteristic polynomials, i.e. $\det(xI-AB)=\det(xI-BA)$. When $A$ and $B$ are square matrices, the identity $\det(I+AB)=\det(I+BA)$ clearly follows from the stronger theorem. When the matrices are not square, one can pad them with zeroes to make them square.

Apparently Sylvester was the first person to state this stronger theorem. In an 1883 paper, he wrote:

> The latent roots of the product of two matrices, it may be added, are the same in whichever order the factors be taken.

(Sylvester, J. J., On the equation to the secular inequalities in the planetary theory. *Philosophical Magazine*, 16:267-269, 1883. Reprinted in *The Collected Mathematical Papers of James Joseph Sylvester*, vol. IV (1882-1897). Chelsea, New York, 1973. ISBN 0-8284-02531.)

Both MacDuffee (1933) and Mirsky (1955) attributed this stronger theorem to Sylvester.  However, Sylvester did not prove the theorem in his paper. A proof (for complex matrices, I believe) was given by Thurston in 1931. Turnbull and Aitken gave another proof in 1932.

As you may already know, there is another "[Sylvester's determinant identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_determinant_identity)" that is about a very different statement. While it is a bit confusing to have two theorems bearing very similar names, I think Wikipedia's renaming of Sylvester's determinant theorem to Weinstein–Aronszajn identity is ridiculous.

Comment: Wikipedia is not entirely to blame; the usage appears to have become widespread in at least one subfield a decade before Wikipedia was edited.

Comment: So the identity $\det(1+AB) = \det(1+BA)$ should be called 'Sylvester's determinant theorem'? Or it is too elementary to be attributed?

Comment: @Eli4ph I am not a standards body to decide whether one *should* call the identity by name or not (and by what name), but I am more inclining toward calling the stronger theorem mentioned in my answer "Sylvester's product theorem", "Sylvester's theorem on characteristic polynomial" etc., and recognise the identity $\det(I+AB)=\det(I+BA)$ as an easy consequence of the stronger theorem...

Comment: ...On the other hand, I am strongly against renaming the identity as "Weinstein-Aronszajn identity". First, I don't think Weinstein or Aronszajn intended to generalise $\det(I+AB)=\det(I+BA)$ when they formulated their identities. Second, I don't think it is easy to figure out how the original Weinstein-Aronszajn identity generalises $\det(I+AB)=\det(I+BA)$...

Comment: Third, even if it is a proper generalisation, there is no reason to remove the names of the discoverer (Sylvester) or the first prover of the weaker version from the theorem's name. Wikipedia's renaming is just a major deviation from the usual naming convention in academic literature.