# What is history and source of the "Matrix Determinant Lemma"?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

That is, for square matrix $A$ and vectors $u$ and $v$, $\det(A+uv^T)=(1+v^TA^{-1}u)\det(A)$.

It's easy to find proofs, generalizations, and applications (such as Sherman-Morrison), but does it have a citable origin for its statement, proof, and/or its name?

Comment: Maybe you will find it in the huge compendium of Muir ["Theory of determinants"](https://archive.org/details/theoryofdetermin01muiruoft/page/n5/mode/2up) (second volume for this 1934 edition)

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4105846

Answer (score 0):

I just found that Horn and Johnson credit this to Cauchy.

It would be nice to find it in Muir someday, if it's in there.